# Cómo puedo insertar una data por partes a una tabla en Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

Tengo aproximadamente como 2 millones de registros y quiero insertarlos de 100k en 100k por ejemplo a una tabla en Oracle. Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo. No inserto los 2 millones de frente porque me demoraran mucho. Estoy usando un select para insertar los datos algo asi:

```
          Insert into Mi_Tabla
          Select Campo1 , Campo2, Campo4,....,Sysdate as Fecha
          from Tabla_Origen A
          Left Join(Tabla2) B on A.CodTabla1 = B.CodTabla2;
          Where --- ;
          Commit;
```

La meta es obviamente insertar todos los registros de la tabla de origen (según la consulta dentro del insert) a la tabla destino sin que ninguno se repita. En el ejemplo seria insertar a la tabla 'Mi_Tabla'. Toda ayuda o idea me será de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crearte un bloque PL con un cursor con la select que devuelve todos los datos y recorrerla, de modo que cada n (n=100000) registros realices un commit.

Cuando acabe el bucle realizas un último commit para confirmar los que falten.

más o menos algo así:

```sql
DECLARE 
cursor c_consulta is Select Campo1 , Campo2, Campo4,....,Sysdate as Fecha
          from Tabla_Origen A
          Left Join(Tabla2) B on A.CodTabla1 = B.CodTabla2;
          Where --- ;
v_contador  number := 0;
v_n number := 100000;
begin
   for v_cur in c_consulta loop
      insert into Mi_tabla(campo1, campo2, campo4, ..., fecha) values (v_cur.campo1, v_cur.campo2, v_cur.campo4,...,fecha);
      v_contador:= v_contador +1;
       if MOD(v_contador, v_n) = 0 then
         commit;
       end if;
   end loop;
   commit;
end;
```